# In Python what is the idiomatic way to replace pre/postincrement?

Tags: python

In c-like languages it is not necessary to manually track array indices because the post-increment operator is available. What is the idiomatic way to produce the same result in python 3?

Here is some example code to show what I'd like to do:

```
array = [0, 1, ... ]

i = 0
foo = array[i++]
bar = array[i++]
```

One possible solution would be to manually track the array indices, but that is error prone. Another would be to insert "i += 1" lines between each assignment, but that is busywork and hurts readability. Another would be to use the next() function, which is a good solution but I haven't seen next used in python code commonly.

One example of why this construct is useful is in class instantiation, for example:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, ... baz):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        ...
        self.baz = baz

    def from_list(data_list):
        foo = data_list[0]
        bar = data_list[1]
        ...
        baz = data_list[25]

       return Data(foo, bar, ... baz)
```

Please note that "foo", "bar", "baz", and "Data" are stand in names, they are not actual names of variables that I intend to use. This code is an example only, illustrating a simple (but undesirable) solution for moving data from a list to variables.

Since a class may contain any number of fields, I would prefer a solution that will scale cleanly and is not error prone.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209492/discussion-on-question-by-user-36845364-in-python-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-r).

Answer (score 3):

Starting in Python 3.8 you could say:

```
i = -1
foo = array[(i:=i+1)]
bar = array[(i:=i+1)]
# ...
```

You could also successively `pop()` from the list, removing items as you go:

```
foo = array.pop(0)
bar = array.pop(0)
```

But I have to say that the most "Pythonic" approach is not to get into the situation where you need to do this in the first place.  To me, either the role played in your program by these items  merits giving them special names like `foo` and `bar`—in which case they shouldn't be stored to start with in a container like a `list` that lacks names (use a `dict`, `OrderedDict` or `namedtuple` instead); or they're anonymous, semantically-interchangeable members of a list—in which case it doesn't make much sense to insist on special variable names for them.

If the data are coming in from a non-Python source (decoded from a binary stream via `struct.unpack` for example), then the `namedtuple` from the `collections` standard-library module is a good tool for attaching names to them. It should be done as early as possible.  Or, another way (one of many ways) to re-write your example concisely and scalably might be:

```
class Data:
    fields = 'a b c d e f g h i j'.split()
    def __init__(self, data_list):
        for name, value in zip(self.fields, data_list):
            setattr(self, name, value)
```

Relative to `namedtuple` that has the advantage of coping with variable `data_list` lengths (if you define too few `fields`, some `data_list` items will be wasted; if `data_list` is too short, the corresponding attributes will not be assigned).

Comment: *nod*. It's very plausible that the data may be coming in with no tagging except ordering, though, with the names needing to be added after-the-fact. That's a case where named tuples come in handy, providing a way to map between name-based and order-based worlds.

Comment: "not to get into the situation where you need to do this in the first place." - so in the case where you have to interface with a system that dumps you a list or a string, what do you do? The frame challenge isn't very helpful because I can't ask a billion dollar consortium to change their protocols :/

Comment: @user-36845364 _interface with a system that dumps you a list or a string, what do you do_ Can you give an example of what you’re referring to? I’m confused as to how it relates to the question. Sorry if I’m missing anything obvious!

Comment: @AMC One example is a system that transmits ascii 6-bit strings with comma separated values over vhf, I have no control over the system. The data is read and parsed, the end result would be it going into a python class for easy manipulation and encapsulation.

Comment: @jez thanks for the update. I'm not 100% confident in the way you have fields set up in your last example, but thanks for the ideas, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a slice to multiple variables.

```
foo, bar = array[i:i+2]
```

For your class initializer, I would probably spread the arguments:

```
def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, ..., z):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
    ...
    self.z = z
```

and then call it like:

```
new Data(*data_list)
```

In general, lists should be used for homogeneous data. So usually you will be iterating over lists, you don't need to extract each element into different variables. Heterogeneous data should be in dictionaries or class instances, so you can access them by name rather than indexes.

Comment: "Heterogeneous data should be in dictionaries or class instances, so you can access them by name rather than indexes." Right, which is why I am moving it into a class :P You present 2 different examples, why not make a helper function to unpack the data in your first example using the same method as in your second?

Comment: A helper function can't assign the caller's variables.

Comment: It essentially maps to the first solution: `self.a, self.b, self.c, ..., self.z = data_list`

Comment: You could using closures, nonlocals, etc, if you wanted to. I understand that they essentially map to the same thing. What I am wondering is why you don't use a argument list unpacking wrapper for the first and tuple unpacking for the second.

Comment: because I'm trying to make it pythonic.

Comment: A function with a list of unnamed parameters is hard to understand. Parameters should be named to make the code clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using `next` is "pythonic" here. You may not see it much in python code because this type of dataset isn't that common. Where you do see it is in processing files and communication streams. One advantage of iteration and `next` is that the original dataset doesn't have to be in memory, it may be generated as you go (e.g., reading a file). And it rasies a StopIteration exception when done which may be better than juggling incrementors that can overflow.

Using `next` may be a bit unsightly especially if you want to catch mismatched foo and bar at the end of the sequence, so wrap it in a function

```
def subsequence(seq, num_values):
    """yield fix length subsequences from sequence"""
    seq_iter = iter(seq)
    try:
        while True:
            vals = []
            for _ in range(num_values):
                vals.append(next(seq_iter))
            yield vals
    except StopIteration:
        if not vals:
            return
    raise ValueError("Sequence did not end with foo, bar pairs")

# gets pairs
dataset = list("abcdef")
for foo, bar in subsequence(dataset, 2):
    print(foo, bar)

# fails on last iteration
dataset2 = list("abc")
for foo, bar in subsequence(dataset2, 2):
    print(foo, bar)
```